# why don't use scope maven dependency Management?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

if i define this dependency at parent's pom:

```
<dependencyManagement> 
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework<groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core<artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
```

and in one of the childss:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency> // note: no version declared
      <groupId>org.springframework<groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core<artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

so, the scope? is always compile, or can i specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compile is the default scope for a dependency ([pom reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)). You can specify scope also and it will be inherited